# Ionic on iOS 9 - Allow access to location

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, location

I am developing an app using maps for showing position of the user. I use cordova location plugin to retrieve the position.

On iOS, when the user starts the app a message window appears to allow the app to access the location. Thats a normal behavior on iOS, the normal message says: `name_of_the_app wants to access your location` with buttons for allow or disallow.

But the message that appears in my app, instead of that, says `the app "a_big_route_to_the_file/file.html" wants to access your location`, this is an ugly and "error like" message.

I would like to know if there is a way to show the normal message, only with the name of the app. I can provide code if you require (the source is a bit large).

Comment: check your info.plist there is a string in GPS permission key

Comment: Please show your info.plist file.. so we can get to know.

Comment: There is key in your info.plist like NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription or NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and also string to show in alert..check it

Comment: Thanks everybody, I will check your solutions right now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. just open iOS project of your app from platform folder and open .plist file from it. There you can edit message for location and give name of your app.